# how to put place holder for <%= f.datagrid_filter filter%>?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datagrid

I made a rails application, and I used `datagrid` gem to handle filters, pagination,and orders(ascending and descending). I was supposed to write `<%= f.datagrid_filter filter%>` to filter according to a filed of the table(Ex:`title` field in `topics` table).
Now `<%= f.datagrid_filter filter%>` returns a traditional html input tag like below. 
`<input id="topic_report_title" class="title string_filter" type="text" size="30" name="topic_report[title]">` in the html console.
Now I want to put placeholder in that helper method only.
Can anybody help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to do the following: `<%= f.datagrid_filter filter, :placeholder => "placeholder text"%>`

Comment: Thank you very much for your responce. I tried before only and eventually I got what I wanted.